# How to simplify this logarithm expression: $\log_b(x) = \frac{\log_c(x) }{\log_c(b)}$?

Tags: logarithms

I need to verify the answer of a logarithm expression (note, I'm not a student). I managed to get through high school and college without ever having a math course that taught logarithms--I don't know how.

The expression that I need to simplify is:

$$\frac{\log_2(x^2)}{\log_2(9)}$$

The answer that was given was 3 but I have not been able to establish that this is correct despite finding plenty of information about logarithm rules and properties. It seems like the following property is applicable:

$$\log_b(x) = \frac{\log_c(x) }{\log_c(b)}$$

but I can only see that I would get me to $\log_9(x^2)$.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Unless you know $x$ you cannot evaluate $\log_2 x^2$ to a particular number. If the answer is $3$, then you must have $x=c^{3 \log_c 3}$, for whatever base $c$ you use.

Comment: ...or unless you were given an equality for that expression.

Comment: Is it possible you already know $x=27$? Could you give more context for your problem?

Comment: I'm afraid the 'Simplify' the original expression is the only information I have. We haven't been given a known value for $x$. There is no inequality either.

Comment: User201569, below, suggests that $log_3|x|$ would be the simplified form. Do others concur?

Comment: I think that copper.hat's comment was the most helpful but it appears that I cannot vote for it as an answer since it's just a comment. Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: FWIW, the problem should not have been 'simplify' and the "/" symbol should have been an equals sign. This would have made it such that 3 is the correct answer.

Comment: @bugdrown In that case $-3$ should also be a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

your answer is correct but isnot the most easiest form
log9(x2)=log3|x|

Comment: I don't know. So you're saying we could take the square root of the base and use the absolute value of $x$? So $log_3|x|$ would be the simplified form?

Comment: yes,It is right